# facing query generation issue while datatable ajax processing

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Below are function to generate datatable dynamically using ajax.

what ever query is generated from below code, from tablename is not being included in final query which is causing the issue

```
private function _get_datatables_query()
{
    $this->db->select('company.*, cities.name as company_city, states.name as company_state, countries.name as company_country');
    $this->db->from($this->table.' as company');
    $this->db->join(CITIES.' as cities','cities.id = '.$this->table.'.company_city_id' ,'left');
    $this->db->join(STATES.' as states','states.id = '.$this->table.'.company_state_id' ,'left');
    $this->db->join(COUNTRIES.' as countries','countries.id = '.$this->table.'.company_country_id' ,'left');
    $this->db->join(COMPANY_DATABASE.' as company_database','company_database.cdb_company_id = '.$this->table.'.company_id' ,'left');


    if($this->ion_auth->is_customer())
      $this->db->where('company_database.cdb_customer_id',csession('user_id'));

    $this->db->where('company.company_delete_status',NOT_DELETED);    


    $i = 0;

    foreach ($this->column_search as $item) // loop column 
    {
      if($_POST['search']['value']) // if datatable send POST for search
      {
        if($i===0) // first loop
        {
          $this->db->group_start(); // open bracket. query Where with OR clause better with bracket. because maybe can combine with other WHERE with AND.
          $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
        }
        else
        {
          $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
        }

        if(count($this->column_search) - 1 == $i) //last loop
          $this->db->group_end(); //close bracket
      }
      $i++;
    }
     
    if(isset($_POST['order'])) // here order processing
    {
      $this->db->order_by($this->column_order[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
    } 
    else if(isset($this->order))
    {
      $order = $this->order;
      $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
    }
  }

  function get_datatables()
  {
    $this->_get_datatables_query(); 

    
    if($_POST['length'] != -1)
    $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);

    // $qu = $this->db->get_compiled_select();
    log_message('error','complied uery : '.$this->db->get_compiled_select());
    
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
  }

  function count_filtered()
  {
    $this->_get_datatables_query();
    
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->num_rows();
  }

  public function count_all()
  {
    // $this->db->from($this->table);
    $this->_get_datatables_query();

    
    return $this->db->count_all_results();
  }
```

I am running this query, I am getting below response

```
Query error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `company_database`.`cdb_customer_id` = '19'
AND `company`.`company_delete_' at line 2 - Invalid query: SELECT *
WHERE `company_database`.`cdb_customer_id` = '19'
AND `company`.`company_delete_status` = 0
ORDER BY `company_id` DESC
 LIMIT 50
```

**as you can see i am already adding**  `$this->db->from($this->tabl.'as company')`

and the real fun is that whenever i add

```
if($this->ion_auth->is_customer())
      $this->db->where('company_database.cdb_customer_id',csession('user_id'));
```

only then this type issue is generated.
otherwise its working fine.

Comment: And seems like whenever I am using function from helper in query directly,  i am facing this issue.

Comment: I have tried to remove helper function but found no issue with that.

Comment: Surely your `datatable` and `ajax` tags are irrelevant to your problem, right? This is purely about generating a valid SQL statement, using your PHP framework. You can [edit] your question.

Comment: (Also, just as a side note: For actual DataTables questions, you would use the `datatables` tag - not `datatable`. Hover your mouse over a tag to read its summary description.)

Comment: I have updated tags @andrewJames

Comment: Thank you for your edit, but let me ask again in a different way: Why does your question talk about "_...while datatable ajax processing_"? How is that relevant to your specific problem? Why have you tagged your question with `ajax`? Where is that relevant to your specific problem? Same for `datatables`. Irrelevant tags should be removed. Or, if they are relevant, can you clarify _how_ and _why_ they are relevant?

Comment: because I am using database with server side processing functionality so i have included it.

Comment: Included where? I don't see any use of DataTables or Ajax in your question.

Comment: but i don't face issue in datatable functionality. so you are right. i will remove the tag

Comment: The query in the error message doesn't look like anything your code would generate. Where are the `SELECT` clauses (the error just shows `SELECT *`)? Where are the joins?

Comment: It looks like you're using a query builder but those are transient and should not be stored as a class property. Where is `$this->db` created?

Comment: Yes. it answered by question. Thank you. @KarlKnechtel